# Sending null variable to methods and compare them with Entity null variables in Linq

Tags: linq, null, entity

I have a method, I'm sending username, password, emails vs. to this method and I'm querying with Linq if there is same record. But when user send a null value it is not same as the linq entities null value it returns false.

The code is here :

```
public int GetTheUserID(string login, string pass, bool isAD)
{
        try
        {
            if (pass == null) {  } 
            if (query.Any()) query = query.Where(x => (x.LoginName == login) && (x.Password_ == pass) && (isAD == x.ADUser) && (x.Deleted == false));
            else query = Entity.SecurityUsers.Where(x => (x.LoginName == login) && (x.Password_ == pass) && (isAD == x.ADUser) && (x.Deleted == false));
            if (query.Any())
            {
                singleresult.TransactionResult = query.FirstOrDefault();
                return singleresult.TransactionResult.ID;
            }
            else return 0;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return 0;
        }
}
```

For example if the password comes null , and also if there is same record with this user credentials and password null  " x.Password_ == pass " not returning true.

Here pass can have value or may come as null. I can't write "x.Password is null" or "x.password == null" but the last one has no problem why mine has?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in this way :

```
public int GetTheUserID(string login, string pass, bool isAD)
    {
        try
        {
            if (query.Any()) query = query.Where(x => (x.LoginName == login) 
                  && ((pass == null) ? x.Password_ == null : x.Password_ == pass) 
                  && (isAD == x.ADUser) && (x.Deleted == false));
            else query = Entity.SecurityUsers.Where(x => (x.LoginName == login) 
                  && ((pass == null) ? x.Password_ == null : x.Password_ == pass)
                  && (isAD == x.ADUser) && (x.Deleted == false));
            if (query.Any())
            {
                singleresult.TransactionResult = query.FirstOrDefault();
                return singleresult.TransactionResult.ID;
            }
            else return 0;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: First of all ,thanks for your answer Maryam.I'm curious about Is there any different ways to solve this issue. Because I have lots of tables in same situtaion and they have lots of columns that can be return null . So it will make lots of complex code and will become nasty. What you think?

Comment: Well.. if I must and if this is the only way , I will use it any way . A ternary  operation didn't come across my mind . it's sensible. But it seems linq or entity framework has a bug isn't it?

Comment: I've search and found that in ADO there is no `Null` and you should write it as `DBNull.value`, when you put directly Null in an linq query its compiler may turns it to `DBNull.value` automatically and then passes it to ADO but when you indirectly pass it as a variable it can not do this transform so `null!=Dbnull.value`

Comment: I see .. but we can't say if (pass==null) {pass=DBNull.value} . So as you explain ternary operation seems more  handy.

Comment: So if we create a Database Access Object (DAO) layer and transfer the Entity varibles in c# objects also DBnull becomes null .  Thank you very much for your Help Maryam. That's more readible code.